# JWPlayer doesn't load a video

Tags: javascript, html, css, jwplayer

I have problem, JW player doesn't load a video. Maybe unsupported format (AVI) or I am using wrong URL.

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "/filmy/Oko_bere.avi",
        image: "logo.png",
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm... did you try removing the first slash in "/filmy/Okobere.avi"? That first slash represents the top directory of the website, which might be tripping up your code.
Also, AVI files tend to be quite large. If your file is too big, it might just be taking a long time to download. You could try converting to a different format such as MP4, or embedding a YouTube video.

Comment: I tried to embed mp4 video, it didn't worked, AVI has +- 1 hour 30 minutes and 600MB, yes, i tried to remove first slash.

Comment: JW Player supports only MP4 and FLV. No AVI.

Comment: I read somewhere, that you can also use AVI somehow with playlist.

Comment: No, you can't. If you "read it somewhere," it was wrong.

Comment: Convert your AVI to MP4. Use Handbrake with default options, plus check "Web optimized." http://handbrake.fr/ Then, the URL for the "file" attribute is relative to the calling page.

Comment: Or even easier yet is Freemake, which can also be used to convert to MP4.

Comment: Converted to MP4, removed first slash. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Works, used WAMP, and on server it works, thanks all! :)
Edit: Doesn't show video.. -.-
Edit: Trying to use handbrake

Answer (score 1):

AVI is definitely not supported. Here is a list of all supported formats - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support

Comment: For the web, the only thing is probably Divx based.